# Проверка оплаты через продамус в телеграмм боте

Tags: python, aiogram

Пишу бота на aiogram и возникла такая проблема. У меня есть сформированная ссылка на оплату (продамус) https://payform.ru/qa2zbTm/, бот присылает ее и если пользователь оплатил - отправляет следующее сообщение с инструкциями, иначе бот ничего не отправляет, ждем оплаты. Каким образом проверить, произвел ли пользователь оплату ? Вроде перечитал всю вспомогательную документацию продамуса, но все равно ничего не понял((

Answer (score 0):

Из документации Prodamus видно, что получать уведомления об оплате можно только с помощью вебхука.

Там есть даже опциональный параметр "urlNotification", который нужен для уведомлений.

> служебный URL-адрес для уведомления интернет-магазина о поступлении оплаты по заказу
> в случае успешной обработки запроса, должен вернуть ответ с кодом 200
> P.S. Для того, чтобы система учла этот параметр, также должен быть передан параметр sys"

Это ссылки на документы по настройке уведомлений

[Тут искать использование аргумента urlNotification](https://help.prodamus.ru/payform/integracii/rest-api/instrukcii-dlya-samostoyatelnaya-integracii-servisov#primer-programmnogo-koda-formirovaniya-ssylki-dlya-demo-formy)

[Тут информацию об использовании вебхука](https://help.prodamus.ru/payform/uvedomleniya/kak-ustroena-otpravka-uvedomlenii-ob-oplate)